# Oracle SQL Get unique symbols from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with descriptions of smth. For example:

```
My_Table
id   description
================
1    ABC
2    ABB
3    OPAC
4    APEЧ
```

I need to get all unique symbols from all "description" columns.
Result should look like that:

```
symbol
================
A
B
C
O
P
E
Ч
```

And it shoud work for all languages, so, as I see, regular expressions cant help.
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean for all languages? all dbms?

Comment: What is the maximum string length?  Does the order of the results matter?

Comment: No, only Oracle SQL. I mean that in "description" column could be text at any languague: english, french, russian etc. Input string could be any size, output string should contain one symbol(as in example, one record for one symbol). Order doesnt matter.

Comment: The input string can't be any size.  The table itself will define a maximum size for the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with    cte (c,description_suffix) as
        (
            select  substr(description,1,1)
                   ,substr(description,2)
            from    mytable
            where   description is not null

            union all

            select  substr(description_suffix,1,1)
                   ,substr(description_suffix,2)
            from    cte
            where   description_suffix is not null
        )
select    c
         ,count(*) as cnt
from      cte
group by  c
order by  c
```

or

```
with    cte(n) as
        (
            select      level 
            from        dual 
            connect by  level <= (select max(length(description)) from mytable)
        )
select  substr(t.description,c.n,1) as c
       ,count(*)                    as cnt
from            mytable t
        join    cte c
        on      c.n <= length(description)
group by substr(t.description,c.n,1)
order by c
```

---

```
+---+-----+
| C | CNT |
+---+-----+
| A |   4 |
| B |   3 |
| C |   2 |
| E |   1 |
| O |   1 |
| P |   2 |
| Ч |   1 |
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks so much, thats exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a numbers table and populate it with all the relevant ids you'd need (in this case 1..maxlength of string)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  locate(your_table.description, numbers.id)   AS symbol
FROM
  your_table
INNER JOIN
  numbers
    ON  numbers.id >= 1
    AND numbers.id <= CHAR_LENGTH(your_table.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(ll,LEVEL,1)) OP --Here DISTINCT(SUBSTR(ll,LEVEL,1)) is used to get all distinct character/numeric in vertical as per requirment
FROM
( 
    SELECT LISTAGG(DES,'') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) ll 
    FROM My_Table  --Here listagg is used to convert all values under description(des) column into a single value and there is no space in between
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(ll);
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers.  Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Your answer is in the moderation queue because it has been flagged as low-quality.